# Is there a way to create a dynamic table with unique names separating it by months?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

The filter will not work in my case because the data I have will change all the time (sometimes it will have a lot of names on it, and sometimes it may have only a few names).

I have 2 sheets. 1 with 12 months of data export from online sources and another sheet where a Pivot table was created with all the names separated months.

I mean, I understand how to find and copy uniques values to another place, but I don't know how I can get the results I need.

I need a table with beneficiaries names that are appearing for the first time in every month, but the names need to be separate by months as well. However, each month values need to be compared with previous months and not directly/only with all 12 months data.

I am not sure if I need to do it using the datasheet or could it be from the pivot table with the names by month.

You can see in the image the result I need to get

I am clueless in how to achieve this.

desired result

[image]

ps: I did post a similar thread on https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/index.php?thread/1227259-vba-code-to-create-a-new-table-with-unique-names-separating-it-by-months/&postID=1233806#post1233806

Comment: Which version of Excel are you using?  I'm not sure about being able to do it within the pivot, but a calculated column in the raw data could show the month a new name appears - used with an Excel table so the pivot looks at the table and not an every changing range of cells.  Not sure about the 'No new names' though.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook I use excel 2019. Well don't really need to be from the pivot table, it can be from the 12 months data I have in 1 of the sheets (therefore, need to keep in mind the data will be different each time). I don't know how I can do it, so the new table will only show the new names compared with previous months (like the images). 
_"No new names"_ is not really necessary, can be 0, empty or not even show in the table (it is only, so the user will know that in this month there are no new names).

Comment: One way would be to add a couple of columns to your raw data - if the date is in column A1:A16 and name is in B1:B16 - `=IF(COUNTIF($B$1:B2,B2)=1,A2,0)` (new date column) and  `=IF(COUNTIF($B$1:B2,B2)=1,B2,"")` (new name column) - then pivot on the two new columns.  You'll need to filter out the year 1900 - that will appear for any row with no data to show.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook it is working, thank you. Would it work if I give a name to the table? Because sometimes the Data will be very long and I think the range of the expending rows could slow it or even crash.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook maybe could you create a answer so I could vote on it to mark as solved the question? Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option :

[Excel.Sheet](https://covid19.framadrop.org/r/mPEfNAtmhK#Oacjkjs77BANdvki42rYnYLE2br9H6JceDJDfbm228M=)

[image: Excel.Names]

Cell with orange background : standard formulas (dragging down needed)

Cells with green background : array formulas

For this example, the sheet could manage 100 records. "Orange formulas" need to be dragged down to extend this limit.
Formulas used : `MONTH`,`FILTER`,`INDIRECT`,`IF`,`COUNTIF`,`COUNT`,`OFFSET`

Brief description :

Column A:B  : name of the person + month (as date format !). You can copy paste your value to test.

Columns F:I : First we order the table. With this new table we "code" the new (1) and the already known person (0).

Columns L:O : We filter the table to keep only the new people.

Columns U:Y : We generate another table which contains the month with no new people.

Columns AC:AE : We combine the 2 previous created tables and we pivot.

Column AH : result.

I hope the mechanic would be clear enough.